How can I define a surface between two circular edges, that bulges outwards?
I am trying to make models of my sculptures. Before, I constructed these models using OpenSCAD, I would like to switch to Blender. But I have issues to succeed, things appear to be very complex in Blender that were simple and straight forward in OpenSCAD.
Those sculptures are defined by two circular or oval edges in two planes that are slightly tilted to each other. The outer surface of the sculptures is the connection between those closed edges, but slightly curved outwards, so that a Donut like form emerges. Here is a picture of such form:

You can see an outer circular edge that runs all around the form and an inner circular edge that is smaller, slightly tilted to another plane. Both edges are connected by two surfaces, the volume between those surfaces is "inflated" so that the surfaces bulge outwards, forming a volume.
I fail to find a way to construct this in Blender. I can define the two circles and create a bridge between them. I even managed to be able to alter those circles afterwards. But I fail to bulge that surface between the edges. And define a second bridge/face between them. How can that be done in Blender? Done such, that the bulging is natural, not defined in manually defined points and manually positioned?
Please excuse if I mix up the terminology, as you can certainly see I am completely new to Blender.

so it's a torus (doughnut) but there's a crease going on the outside and inside, and the crease isn't aligned with the default edge flow of the torus topology?

@MarkusvonBroady In this case it is such a torus, correct, though the original construction is a circular extrusion of a polygon. Other sculptures have ,multiple edges, though, this is just the most simple one I chose for the description.

It's same problem as here:
How to create a extruded 4-star shape that is rotated inwards?
Profile 180
Create a profile with some rotational symmetry, I joined 2 arcs for 180° rotational symmetry and one repeated crease due to uneven resolution:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Stuff after the viewer just connects all points together into one cyclic curve (just noticed there's two "Set Spline Cyclic" nodes, it's a mistake, one would be enough).
Split Start/End

Imgur mirror
Twist

Imgur mirror
Assemble Pieces

Imgur mirror
Result
I added a very strong ridge cavity effect to accent the edge, but maybe the profile shape should have a more dramatic change instead...

Imgur mirror


Wow, thanks, it will take me a while to understand all this. I will work through it and report back. The rendered image appears to show a different form, one with a continuous edge, but that is just a question of adjustment. I will try to understand the core concepts of the answer first. As said this is still all alien to me.

@arkascha there's a chance I misunderstood the question, but it seems your profile is just more similar to an eye shape, as opposed to mine being circular but with uneven density of points, which makes a very subtle crease upon subdivision.

LOL, I have no idea what you just expressed. This language is so alien to me. But I will get there, gimme a bit of time. Just trying to replicate your answer. So far I found the Goemetry nodes, modeling now.

The shape in the picture I sent has indeed two circular edges, so it is circular, not eye shaped. I could provide more pictures, more sculptures, but I doubt that is the point. I think I just need a bit of time to wrap my mind around the concepts. I will get there, I know how to program, so I will understand this.

That is so valuable, but actually not what I had in mind. I tried again to explain what I am trying to achieve: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156772/sculpture-model
